# Cannot export anything from type script module in VS 2015 + node js

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I one file I have `export class Foo{}`. In another:

```
import {Foo} from "./module.ts";
var foo: Foo = new Foo();
```

When i try to run this i got:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { export class Foo
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

I'm using VS 2015 + node js + type script (1.8.6.0 that I downloaded from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48593). Is there something wrong with my settings ?

In fact no method of importing/exporting from here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `import {Foo} from "./module.ts"` with `import {Foo} from "./module"`.
`var foo: Foo = new Foo();` can be written as `var foo = new Foo();` since tsc is able to deduce its type.

Comment: I knew it was something simple, I just needed another pair of eyes.